# Upgrading from 12.10 now that it's end of lifed?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my 12.10 system, but I can't even run the Software Updater because it dies when trying to find the now non-existent quantal packages. Similarly with command line level apt-get upgrading. Very frustrating.

How do you upgrade now that ubuntu's wiped out those packages that are needed to upgrade?

Comment: The relevant information is at http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Comment: ubuntu 12.10 [went End Of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_life) in May. The above question has answers about how to solve this, though a fresh install of a supported release could be better - this would also mean that you could get Software updates etc.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade"? I know it might not be the best thing to skip releases so much but since it is so close to 12.04 fundamentally I don't think it would be a problem. Try that and if that fails then just do a normal install with a new 14.04 disk and use the same username and password and it should copy over files and installed packages just fine